# Sort a generic List

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, generics, sorting

I have a `MyObject` class that contains a `CreationDate As Date` Property.

What is the best way to obtain a sorted by `CreationDate` `List(Of MyObject)`?

The quicker way and the most performant one.

Comment: @hatchet that was a question for C#, and not for VB syntax it's important syntactically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well with LINQ you could use:

```
Dim sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationDate) _
                     .ToList()
```

EDIT: If you've already got a `List(Of T)` you could use the in-place `Sort` method with a custom comparer. That *may* be faster. It may not. I suspect it's unlikely to be a *significant* difference in performance, which is what you should be concerned about.

As a rule of thumb, I'd suggest:

- Work out what constitutes "adequate" performance
- Write code in the most readable way (which is likely to be LINQ rather than a custom comparer, IMO)
- Measure that code
- If it isn't fast *enough*, try an alternative approach, and measure that. Compare the difference in performance with the difference in readability/maintainability.

Comment: Jon, this _must_ be a duplicate of something.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Quite possibly. I always end up getting torn when it's one minute to answer a question or four minutes to find a really good duplicate...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was hoping you had the one minute that I did not :-)

Comment: @serhio The fastest way to retrieve a list sorted by, e.g. date, would be to insert new items in date order. Of course, adding items would then be slower.

Comment: @serhio: I don't know, to be honest. I suspect the in-place sort and `OrderBy` use different sorting algorithms - and some will be faster in some cases than others. I strongly suspect that the performance won't differ *significantly* though.

Comment: Using the sort method of `List(Of T)` might be faster than LINQ.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: It might be. It might not be. It's unlikely to be significantly different. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, probably both variants use a quicksort algorithm internally. The only difference in speed might come from enumerating the enumerator with LINQ, unless LINQ's sort method has an optimization for `IList`.

Comment: Sidenote: VB.NET supports [implicit line continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4.aspx) since VS2010.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, but last time I checked that would only work if the line wasn't a valid statement on its own - in this case it would be. Will try it to see though...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Just tried it, and indeed without the `_` it fails. Moving the `.` to the previous line fixes it, but that looks ugly to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, in VB.NET it's different than in C#, you need to end the line witht the `.`, the you can continue on the next line. It is a matter of taste. But i prefer query syntax in VB.NET anyway which is much more powerful than in C#.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Each to their own. I like the smaller language of C# - I'm happy to use the extension methods directly where query expressions don't cover it.

Answer (score 3):

Lists have a sort method. One overload of it allows to specify a comparison

```
unsorted.Sort(Function(x, y) x.CreationDate.CompareTo(y.CreationDate))
```

Comment: No, I didn't. I assume that unsorted is a `List(Of MyObject)`. This is not LINQ! However, The assignment was wrong.

Comment: +1 This is more efficient if OP wants to order the original collection instead of creating a new one.

Comment: My intellisense works with VB as well as with C# with this example. No need to specify types explicitly. I am using VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `IComparer` interface and define it's `Compare` method to check the date of your `MyObject` object:

```
public class MyObjectComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(MyObject firstObject, MyObject secondObject)
    {
        return firstObject.CreationDate.Compare(secondObject.CreationDate);
    }
}
```

Note: I assumed your `CreationDate` was of type `DateTime` but you can implement the compare function as you wish.

Then to sort you list according to your Comparer:

```
myListObject.Sort(new MyObjectComparer<MyObject>());
```